# How can we send email at installation time of extension

Tags: email, installation

I want send an email at installation time of the extension. But didn't find any solution yet. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In which installation step you want to send the email?

Comment: Once any user install my extension an email should send from their server to any specific id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your email function in SQL setup file of the extension, so it will send email upon installation.

If you can manage it through database by making an entry that will be good.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a setup script with your extension and add your email code in there. It will automatically fire upon installation.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-6.html

Answer (score 0):

This way you could proceed:

Use observer **controller_action_layout_load_before** (This will fire on each page load)

Inside it use below code:

```
public function sendEmail() {

    $isEmailSent = 0; /* get Dynamic value from DB */

    if ($isEmailSent == 0) {
        $modules = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules')->children();
        $allInstalledModules = (array) $modules;

        if (isset($allInstalledModules['Your_Module'])) {
            /* Your email code here */
            /* Set some value in db as  $isEmailSent=1 */
        }
    }
}
```